# Can you create objects faster than JVM GC can handle ? Thus OOM occurs?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am just wondering what if I create/delete objects in the following manner, would the GC be able to handle it ?

1. create millions of objects.
2. wait for 5 minutes.
3. delete the objects
4. create them right away after deletion (without wait/delay)

I think the CPU usage would go up as it runs the GC, but is it possible that the GC would not be able to catch as it tries to reclaim the heap ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything in the jls to prohibit it, but I doubt it'll happen on most JVMs. The allocation will intitiate a GC if needed, and wait for it to complete.

Comment: You can actually 'outrace' the GC if you have a lot of finalizers (or they run slowly). The finalization queue basically gets too long.

Comment: Thanks. Is it because the finalizers HAVE to run so it gets higher priority over GC ?

Answer (score 3):

If the heap survives the initial surge, you're fine.

You can OOM if you allocated too many objects, speed has nothing to do with it.

But if you don't have more active objects than the heap can handle, you won't go OOM. Part of allocating a new object is checking to see if a GC is necessary. So you can't "out race it".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so basically, the GC puts any memory allocation of objects on hold UNTIL it has enough memory to allocate it.  It makes sense.